# How do I bind a List<string> to an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

In my presenter I have this property:

```
public List<string> PropertyNames { get; set; }
```

And I want to list out the names with a ItemsControl/DataTemplate like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyNames}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Since the generic list doesn't have named properties, how do I reference the **value** in my Binding statement?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

let me answer this, it's just `{Binding}`.

Comment: FYI, '.' works either with or without 'Path='. Blank is implicitly interpreted as a '.'. So you can write {Binding}, {Binding .}, or {Binding Path=.} Note that {Binding Path=} won't work - you'll get a XAML compiler error.

Comment: haha. Question is asked at 11:15 and answered by exact same person just a minute later. Then answer is accepted :) well done.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to accomplish the same thing is to simply use:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyNames}"/>
```

By default, this will create a vertical StackPanel and add each element in its own TextBlock. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx), this works for any of the following:

- A string.
- A DateTime object.
- A UIElement object.
- A Panel control that contains an Ellipse and a TextBlock.